# How to highlight the selected navigation menu in SB-Admin bootstrap Template?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using SB-ADMIN bootstrap template in my project. I want to high light the selected Menu. I tried this code, the navigation menu will be highlighted But the right side container it's not loaded. Please find the attached file.

```
$("#exampleAccordion").on("click", function(event){
    $("#exampleAccordion").find("li").removeClass('active');
    $(event.target).closest("li").addClass('active');
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

[image]

Comment: you are preventing the click event by `event.preventDefault();`. So it will not redirect to the page

Comment: yes it will block redirect. so i have blocked into this. I want highlight the active menu

Comment: Try to add something in the script level or add it in the js onload by comparing url and href. Will post answer soon

Answer (score 4):

Its better to handle it in the script side. If you still want to use js for it, then use the following code. This should be attached to each page.

Assumes that you are using relative url for menu link. like **/abc/cdf/chart.html**. If not change the logic in the `$(this).attr('href') == window.location.pathname` condition

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#exampleAccordion a").each(function (index, element) {
        if ($(this).attr('href') == window.location.pathname) {
            $(this).parent().addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

The code will check the current url path with the menu urls, and if finds any match, then it will add class(`active`) to the parent

Answer (score 0):

Following with the suggestion from @Aneesh but for the SB Admin 2, considering the nested collapsed items, I came up with this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log(window.location.pathname);
    $("#accordionSidebar a").each(function(index, element) {
        if ($(element).attr('href') == window.location.pathname) {
            if ($(element).hasClass('collapse-item') == true) {
                $(element).parent().parent().parent().addClass("active");
                $(element).parent().parent().addClass("show");
                $(element).addClass("active");
            } else {
                $(element).parent().addClass("active");
            }
        }
    });
});
```